# How to connect male wire to stiff piece of metal with holes

Tags: arduino

This is my second day playing around with Arduinos, so I don't particularly know hardware-related concepts and terminology. I'm trying to connect a simple male wire to a button (see image). The only thing I've tried is simply threading the hole with the pin, but that clearly doesn't work.

[image]

I haven't found any other solutions since I'm not sure how to refer to the shape in question. I did purchase an Arduino kit, not just the Uno, but this was an external part so I wasn't able to find any instructions. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Male wire? Wire has no gender. Those terminals are designed to be soldered to with stranded wire wrapped through it.

Comment: Do you own a soldering iron?

Comment: I do not; no. Would I be able to use tape to quickly and temporarily connect it? If so, what tape?

Comment: @Daneolog The results are spotty enough with looping stranded wire and then twisting it around itself really tight like a twisty tie. You could try it with solid strand wire but don't expect anywhere near a reliable connection, especially if you're moving and poking at it (it is a button after all). Expect the connection to be broken half the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solder a wire onto the metal tab.

You can also crimp a connector onto the wire and push the connector onto the switch tab.

Google `crimp on wire terminals` .

Bottom right one in the picture.

[image]

Comment: I will definitely look into it! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Actually, how would I search for this type of connector? Is it just a "crimp connector" or is there another name for it?

Comment: edited answer with search terms

Comment: I've found [this](https://www.elecdirect.com/crimp-wire-terminals/disconnect-terminals-fully-insulated/slide-non-insulated-male-16-14-250-100pk) which seems to be the one I want (male wire crimp thingy), but it seems to not have the "rollable" metal on the top like in your picture. How would I attach the connector that I linked?

Comment: You found a male uninsulated crimp terminal - you want a female 1/8" terminal (these are sometimes called "Faston Terminals".)  However, the most common method of connecting to the terminals on your button is soldering.  If you do much electronics, you WILL need a soldering iron, so get one now.

Answer (score 1):

This type of terminal is frequently called a solder lug. The way you use them is by inserting the wire through the hole, possibly wrapping it around the metal tang if you like, and soldering the wire in place.

Comment: The issue that I am having with that is that the wire is very stiff, and (unless I'm not putting enough force) doesn't wrap around the terminal.

Comment: you do not wrap the wire ... refer to your picture of the switch ... insert end of wire vertically through the hole, then lay the wire to the left so that the end of the wire is caught under the lip of the hole ... heat tab and wire with a soldering iron ... apply solder ... slip heat-shrink tubing over the tab

Comment: @Daneolog As I said, wrap if you want, it's not required. The required part is soldering it.